# Как исправить ошибку при открытии общей папки в virtualbox, ubuntu (x64)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

у меня возникла проблема, после создания общей папки в в virtual box, ubuntu, возникла проблема, а именно при попытке открыть эту папку всплывает ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/596998/unable-to-install-guest-additions-unknown-filesystem-type-iso9660

Answer (score 1):

> Как вариант.

```
  apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

- reboot системы